# How to weight values for a weighted average

Tags: mean, weighted

I have 100 answers regarding production times in minutes of a certain product from 100 manufacturers around the country. I also know if these companies have met any of the 3 quality standards relating to manufacturing this product. I want to create a standard of what are efficient production times but I also want to include all the data. Anyway, I'd like to know how to weight the production times by quality standards met. I have 4 categories, 0=no, 1=1 standard met, etc. One idea I had is just multiplying the inspection time by the standards met to weight the insp. times. So if one manufacturer took 45 minutes to produce the product and met two standards I could multiply it by two, and at the end of doing this to all of them take the average. Does this sound good? If not any ideas?

Comment: It sounds completely arbitrary to me.  Even if you could tell us how you intend to use this "standard," we cannot possibly know what role the quality standards ought to play for the product's manufacturers or customers.

Comment: Further along the lines of @whuber 's comment, if you think about this is in the context of an optimization or decision or assessment context, try to formulate an "objective function" to be optimized, such as some measure of goodness.  Try to drive as far downstream toward an end problem or use as you can. Let that guide you.